# Setting <f:ajax disabled="true/false" /> with javascript in JSF

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

Using JSF 2.3, is it possible to enalbe/disable ajax just from the client side using javascript?

What I would like to do is have some control (e.g. checkbox) to enable/disable
an auto-save feature using ajax:

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label title="Auto-save inputs">
    <input type="checkbox" id="autoSaveId" />Autosave
  </label>
</div>

<h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}">
  <f:ajax disabled="!$('#autoSaveId').is(':checked')" />
</h:inputText>
```

I have  many such `inputText` and other controls on the page.

I currently have it like this:

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{sessionScope.doAutosave}">
  <f:ajax />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}">
  <f:ajax />
</h:inputText>
```

And on the server I check `sessionScope.doAutosave` to either ignore or process the action. The problem is that the unnecessary ajax calls use network bandwidth so just avoiding the ajax calls altogether (when not required) would be ideal.

Comment: Setting a component to disabled/enabled purely on the client defeats all great JSF security features. So the only way to update this is to set it on the server and update the component. Setting it on the server can be initiated from the client, but then the server can at least check if it is allowed or not.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks - I hadn't thought of the general security implications. I've updated my question with more info about setting it on the server.

Comment: And? What if you put `disabled="#{!sessionScope.doAutosave}"` on the `f:ajax` of the `h:inputText`? And a `render="@form"` on the `f:ajax` of the `h:selectBooleanCheckox`? All plain jsf

Comment: And if using `f:ajax` on a page, results in view expired exceptions in pages on other tabs you have a different problem. Using ajax makes you stay on the same view and hence should not influence any other tabs/pages

Comment: @Kukeltje doing `disabled="#{!sessionScope.doAutosave}"` doesn't really work: it takes the initial value (false), then doesn't pick up the new value when the option is enabled. I would need to render the form or inputs when the option changes, but that will erase anything the user has typed in.

Comment: @Kukeltje You're right about the `f:ajax` not causing the ViewExpiredExceptions - I didn't more testing an it seems it's not the cause. Would still be nice to avoid the network traffic though.

Comment: _"that will erase anything the user has typed in."_ Not if you also add `execute="@form"`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/ddg#25347186

Comment: And look at http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form to reduce network traffic (data not number of requests) in combination with `execute="@this"` on other `f:ajax` tags